# Azure Blob Storage and Python Certificate Error

Tags: python, pandas, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Please help in resolving the certificate error. This occurred for the first time in years..

I am trying to run python on my local machine to read and write data from azure blob container, was able to process successfully then suddenly started getting below certificate error. I do have admin control on my machine..

Since the error we did few scenario analysis and were successful:

- Tried running the same script on another machine, same version of python and sas url
- The script runs on VM and on DevOps on a schedule, same version of python and sas url

Using `Python 3.8.8`

```
ServiceRequestError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1125)
```

Comment: State the scenario details on what, you got the error to understand better!

Comment: @HariKrishna: Kindly review the question and let me know if this clear or need more information..